# How to make cudaMalloc dynamically

Tags: cuda

I need to perform cudaMalloc dynamically to allocate memory for a dynamically expanding array, which size can vary in a wide range. This array represents the result of join operation over two tables, so it can be zero size or come up to maximal amount of data (in case when the tables contain totally similar data).

If I allocate memory due to expectation that the tables' data is almost similar, I can get a huge amount of memory that's not used at all

So, is there some way to perform memory allocation dynamically with CUDA to make memory usage efficient?

Comment: I don't understand the question. cudaMalloc *is* dynamic, runtime memory allocation. Are you asking about having memory allocation done inside a running kernel, or something else?

Comment: Are you somehow expecting cudaMalloc to automagically reserve an extra bit of memory for your array, should you need to expand it?

Comment: I mean that the array is first allocated with minimal size before running the kernel, but it can be expanded (extra memory allocation) while the kernel is running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to dynamically expand previously allocated memory inside a kernel. The closest you get is 'new' and 'delete' on Fermi. But those allocate new chunks, they don't expand your existing chunk. However, I don't see any point in attempting to expand the allocated memory inside a kernel. Just allocate the maximum amount of memory that could be used by the kernels up front. If that means that you don't have enough memory to complete the processing of the data afterwards, then the program would not have been able to handle that case anyway, if you had been able to dynamically expand the memory.

Also, a scheme where you would continously expand the allocated memory to hold new results would require a lot of communication between the threads (since all threads would have to know how many results have currently been found). Instead, don't attempt to create a result set without gaps in it. Let the results of your join be stored throughout the allocated area, in locations that correspond with the thread indexes. Then, scan through the result with a second kernel or with Thrust to gather the results together.